# is there a portable way to manage structure data stored in a mapped file in Linux, without reading it raw byte-by-byte?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

Let's say I want to store a C array (of fixed length `N`) of structures:

```
typedef struct {
  type0 field0;
  type1 field1;
} foo_struct;

foo_struct array[N];
```

in a file, so that the program can read the array from the file, manipulate it, and write it back.

The program could use system call `write` to write each instance of `typen`. Then when we call the program to read, if we assume that `sizeof(typen)` returns the same as before, we can allocate the array in memory, and use `read` to stuff fields.  I assume that due to portability issues, there is no way to reliably stuff the whole structure at once, please correct me if I am wrong.

But that is too slow for my purposes.  Even if I read everything at once into a big buffer, I then have to copy to fields.  What happens is that my data size is "yuuge", but manipulation is sporadic. Reading and copying would take way more time than actual data access.

So I prefer to use `mmap` and I am assuming `mmap` works on-demand basis - again please correct me if I am wrong.

Now, this may be faster, but I will have some trouble accessing the data in memory.

Specifying a return value from `mmap` yourself being a bad idea, the function returns the buffer for you, which is not guaranteed to be aligned, and even if it were aligned on the multiples of `sizeof(foo_struct)`, this would still not portably guarantee that I can access fields with pointers to the struct and `->` operator.

So I think, I have to forget about identifying the structure at all, and just think of my array as a series of chunks of sizes `S0 = sizeof(field0)` `S1 = sizeof(field1)` `S = S0 + S1`, and calculate by hand where the data is, by using pointer arithmetic:

```
buffer + M * S
buffer + M * S + S0
```

Then, even that pointer is not aligned, so if I want to read or write a `fieldn`, I have to split the data into bytes and do it byte-by-byte, which is slow.  Even though there are not so many of these accesses, but then, there are many iterations of this whole process, so I still care to have it as fast as possible.

Is there a way to use `mmap` (or some other way so that I don't have to read the whole yuuge file), but, not have to access data field-by-field and byte-by-byte?

Please also share if some of what I wrote, goes against Linux or common decency, as I am not completely sure that it does not.

Comment: 1) mmap() returns a *page aligned* pointer, with is suitable for any type. 2)`But that is too slow for my purposes.` Did you measure it? How?

Comment: Well...  this is an SSCCE.  The real situation is that the structure can be huge, certainly possibly a few K in size, so I don't want to assume page aligned is OK.  OK, even assuming that page size is no less than the next power of 2 to the structure size, why would the page aligned pointer be suitable?? You do know that portably speaking, there is no such thing as guaranteed alignment for a struct if the pointer is "divisible" by the struct size?

Comment: I did not measure.  I just know the size of the file can be unmeasurably big and I don't want to rely that it is not, and I have many iterations, too. I mean, the thing is on a disk, and yes, there are still plenty of spinning disks out there, I cannot assume it is all flash, and if it spins, it is way too slow.  Please assume that it is too slow like I wrote.

Comment: `read(fd, array, sizeof array);` will work in your case. Similar for `write()` Do check the return values from the functions. (the data file may of course not be portable to other architectures, but that is a different issue)

Comment: @wildplasser I answer your concerns but you don't answer mine, this is no way to carry on a discussion...  I told you this is no good, and yes of course it has to portable, It would work only if it were used by the same compiled program; it has to be possible to restart with the program compiled on a different arch.

Comment: **what** has to be portable, the program or the data? You should specify this in your question. And don't be overly concerned with performance, in normal cases I/O will always be the limiting factor.

Comment: How is the file written?  The alignment requirement on the structure type will not be more stringent than the alignment requirement of the most stringently aligned member of the structure; it is unlikely to be restrictive than 16-byte alignment, and the page size will be aligned probably on a 4 KiB boundary, so the result of `mmap()` will be sufficiently aligned for any structure.  If the output file is a straight binary dump of an array of the structures in memory and the structure contains no pointers, then you can use either `mmap()` or `malloc()`+`read()` to get the data into memory.

Comment: With the data in memory, you can use regular array notation to access the structure elements — there's no need to do anything more complex, and no benefit to doing so.  There really aren't any alternatives.  These are both about as portable as the data in the file allows.  It does assume that the file is written on a machine with compatible data types and alignments — both big-endian or little-endian, etc.  If you have to worry about endian-ness, then you have to do more work at some point — details depend on types, etc, and there's not enough information in the question to help with that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you Jonathan.But I continue to not understand what both you and wildplasser are saying about alignment.  There is absolutely no guarantee in the C11 standard, that if a structure is read into a buffer, whose address in virtual memory divides by the sizeof structure, then you can cast the buffer to the pointer to the structure and read the fields.  NONE.  Yes it is LIKELY, but I am not interested in "likely".  I am interested in portability at all costs.

Comment: You're using the wrong language, then.  There is no "portability at all costs" in C.  And any alternative is unlikely to be any better in practice.  I'm not sure what your divisibility criterion is about — it doesn't figure into my understanding of alignment requirements.  Alignment and size are related but not synonymous; the alignment requirement is usually not larger than the size.  I can't think of a scenario where that isn't the case.  And for composite structures (multiple data elements), the size is always larger than the alignment requirement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, I disagree that there is "no portability at all costs" in C.  Yes there is - just like I described, you use `mmap`, work with offsets and sizes of fields, work byte by byte inside the fields, and forget the structure.  What I want to know in the question, is there a better portable way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK forget about "divisibility" then.  You are saying, that there is some "alignment requirement" in the C11 standard, that if the buffer to which we `read` structure, satisfies this "requirement" then we can access the data by fields.  There is no such thing in the C11 standard.

Comment: We are going to have to agree to disagree.  That's grungy and horrid and not worth doing when the direct method works just as reliably and with far less code.  You've not addressed my question of how the file is written.  I'm not really interested any more — we're talking at cross-purposes and you don't seem to be willing to listen to the possibility that you're misinformed or misunderstanding what is possible.  Goodbye.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you I did not mean any disrespect.

Comment: You keep saying to @JonathanLeffler that "there's no guarantee in C11 that...", but then talking about `mmap()`. I hate to break it to you, but there's no guarantee in C11 that `mmap()` exists at all! If you're assuming `mmap()`, you are presumably assuming some sort of Unix-style system, and all that that implies; one thing that that certainly implies is a page-based model, where each page is suitably aligned for any data structure. (Also: I'm assuming it`s the code you want to be portable, not the data, as otherwise the datatypes in your example code need fixing!)

Comment: @psmears yes it says in the question "Linux", so I am assuming Linux.

Comment: @psmears where exactly does it say in POSIX (or any other existing Linux documentation, valid for recent kernels), that page is suitably aligned for any data structure.  Just tell me where it says so.  (By the way, there is no guarantee of anything about the page size, it could be very small, POSIX does not guarantee any minimum size).

Comment: @psmears by the way... `mmap` documentation _does_not_ say it returns page aligned result - only if you supply an argument yourself, which is non-portable of course and a very bad idea, then the Linux kernel will choose a nearby page boundary.  But if you don't supply the hint, the documentation _does_not_ say it will return page-aligned.

Comment: LOL. You are really looking at portability the wrong way. If you want your code to be portable, you can't just slavishly stick to standards documents, assuming they say everything you can rely on (they don't), and that you can rely on everything they say (you can't)... they're *helpful*, and the world is a much better place than before POSIX-compliance was common, but they only go so far. In this instance, given you're assuming Linux, you can rely on `mmap()` returning a page boundary, and on that being good enough for any structure...

Comment: ...,because that assumption is hard-baked into the Linux kernel & C libraries, hence is unlikely to change. What you *do* need to worry about (& your question does not address) is things like: (1) Endianness (bytes of words in different orders); (2) Sizes (eg `long` may be 32 or 64 bits); (3) Padding - structures will be padded to ensure the correct alignment of their elements, so the pointer arithmetic in your question where you simply add element sizes to the start of the structure will go wrong. These factors apply to *real, actual* Linux architectures, so are worth coding for.

Answer (score 1):

Just for demonstration purposes, the standard *read struct-array from binary file* :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct omg{
        int num;
        char buff[122];
        double values[23];
        };

#define NNN (3*1024*1024)
#define FILENAME "omg.dat"
#define COUNTOF(a) (sizeof a/sizeof a[0])

struct omg array[NNN];

int main(void)
{
int fd;
int ret, ii, jj;

fprintf(stderr, "Sizeof array[0] is %zu\n", sizeof array[0] );
        /* initialise the array to nonsence */
for (ii=0; ii < COUNTOF(array); ii++) {
        array[ii].num=ii;
        sprintf(array[ii].buff, "Hello world %d", ii);
        for (jj=0; jj < COUNTOF(array[0].values); jj++) {
                array[ii].values[jj] = ii / (jj+1) ;
                }
        }

fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0660);
if (fd < 0) return 1;

ret = read(fd, array, sizeof array);
fprintf(stderr, "Read %d/ %zu\n", ret, sizeof array);

        /* modify the nonsence */
for (ii=0; ii < COUNTOF(array); ii++) {
        array[ii].num += 1;
        sprintf(array[ii].buff, "Hello world %d", array[ii].num);
        for (jj=0; jj < COUNTOF(array[0].values); jj++) {
                array[ii].values[jj] = array[ii].num / (jj+1) ;
                }
        }

ret = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
fprintf(stderr, "Seek = %d\n", ret);


ret = write(fd, array, sizeof array);
fprintf(stderr, "Wrote %d/ %zu\n", ret, sizeof array);

close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

---

Result:

```
plasser@pisbak$ vi readstruct.c
plasser@pisbak$ cc -Wall -O2 readstruct.c
plasser@pisbak$ time ./a.out
Sizeof array[0] is 312
Read 981467136/ 981467136
Wrote 981467136/ 981467136

real    0m3.972s
user    0m1.689s
sys     0m0.782s
```

---

Now, I wouldn't call reading plus writing 900MB in 4 seconds *slow*.
Most of the user CPU is probably consumed by the `sprintf()` calls.